US IRS Form 4562: section 179 for a trust
The first year we rented a house, someone else did our form 4562, including the first part for section 179 limitation.
This year, we created a revocable trust and added that house to it.  Instructions say section 179 can't be used for property owned by a trust.  Does that mean we must stop using that section?  Do we have to amend earlier years to remove it?
I searched all the forms for that year and can't find that the numbers were used anywhere, for limitation or any other purpose.

What type of trust?

The IRC Sec. 179(a) says this:

A taxpayer may elect to treat the cost of any section 179 property as an expense which is not chargeable to capital account. Any cost so treated shall be allowed as a deduction for the taxable year in which the section 179 property is placed in service.

The IRC Sec. 179(d)(4) says this:

This section shall not apply to estates and trusts.

Generally, what it means that a taxpayer who's an estate or trust (i.e.: filing form 1041) cannot use this section.
For a revocable grantor trust that is not the case, since the taxpayer is still the grantor, not the trust. Until the trust becomes irrevocable it is disregarded for tax purposes.
